# Error on GET request to steam market

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, get, jsonp

I am attempting to do a GET request to get the item price info for a single item on the steam market.

Here is the exact angularJS script I am using:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('csgo', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.jsonp("http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20P250%20%7C%20Steel%20Disruption%20%28Factory%20New%29").success(function(response) { 
        $scope.values = response;
        console.log(response); 
    });
});
</script>
```

When I try to do this in my browser I get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : ?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=StatTrak™ P250 | Steel Disruption (Factory New):1
```

Inside my chrome browser console. I then click the link in error message (?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=StatTrak™ P250 | Steel Disruption (Factory New):1)

And it takes me to a line that is:

```
{"success":true,"lowest_price":"1,09&#8364; ","volume":"348","median_price":"1,01&#8364; "}
```

So I actually get the information, but it gives an error and underlines the JSON response in red. Anyone know the issue?

I am using nodejs, express, and angular.

EDIT:

I tried a different URL: https://angularjs.org/greet.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&name=Super%20Hero

And it worked with this URL. So im not sure why the original URL I am trying to request is not working. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @Huey Thanks for responding. I tried deleting the '/' and it still gave me the error : /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `JSONP`, it should call `JSON_CALLBACK()` to process the results. You can refer to [Angular JSONP document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp) for more information, it also provides a [live demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) of how `JSON_CALLBACK` is used.

So in your case, you should call like below

```
$http.jsonp("http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20P250%20%7C%20Steel%20Disruption%20%28Factory%20New%29").success(function(response) { 
    $scope.values = response;
    console.log(response); 
});
```

If you server handle `JSON_CALLBACK` correctly, all errors should be gone.

### Update

I just look into the [Steam Community](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API/Feedback)

> There is a lack of support for the JSONP protocol and the API's
>   acceptable usage policy requires that the API key is not to be shared.
>   As described, using this API key inside of a Javascript file (which is
>   downloaded in full source by the client) would be against the policy
>   that Valve has provided

They don't support `JSONP`, and they don't support `CORS` either. It looks like you can access steam api from Angular.

Comment: Hey @Rebornix - Thanks for the answer. I changed my $http.jsonp line to be what you had, but still got the error. I am guessing I need to do more than that. When you say "If your server handles JSON_CALLBACK correctly" what does that mean? Do I need to change something somewhere else? Sorry I am pretty new to this.

Comment: @httpNick you are using nodejs, I suppose you need to return json response as  `res.jsonp(obj)` in your node code.

Comment: Yeah I am. Where would that line be placed? I have a "server.js" file which is where im guessing id have that, but not sure where I would place that line.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, you are calling steam's api, so there is nothing to do with your node code. Pls see my update it seems you can't access steam api in Angular, you have to call the api from node.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I just have to figure that out haha.

Comment: Do you mean you can't fetch prices from steam in any way from the browser? I was going to try to use code outside of angularjs in the browser.

Comment: As they don't support `CORS`, I think it's not possible to fetch anything from stream in your browser.