# return after a series of functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I have tried to do this with [q](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q) as well as [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async), but haven't been able to seem to make it work. After trying those I tried my own way. I didn't think this would work, but I thought I would give it a try. I am confused since there is a callback within a callback in a sense. Here is the function I am wanting to do:

```
var getPrice = function(theData) {
var wep = theData.weapon;
var completed = 0;
for (i = 0; i < theData.skins.length; i++) {
    var currSkin = theData.skins[i];
    theData.skinData[currSkin] = {};
    for (k = 0; k < wears.length; k++) {
        csgomarket.getSinglePrice(wep, currSkin, wears[k], false,
            function(err, data) {
                completed++;
                if (!err) {
                    theData.skinData[data.skin][data.wear] = data;
                }
                if (completed === theData.skins.length*wears.length) {
                        return theData;
                    }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I know these kinds of issues are common in javascript as I have ran into them before, but not sure how to solve this one. I am wanting to fill my object with all the data returned by the method:

```
csgomarket.getSinglePrice(wep, currSkin, wears[k], false,
  function(err, data) { });
```

Since each call to `getSinglePrice()` sends off a GET request it takes some time for the responses to come back. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it okay if the answer uses Q?

Comment: @thefourtheye Yeah that is fine. I just couldn't get it to work with q, but it's fine if it uses it!

Comment: can you also post your csgomarket.getSinglePrice function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `csgomarket.getSinglePrice()` needs to be promisified. Here's an adapter function that calls  `csgomarket.getSinglePrice()` and returns a `Q` promise.

```
function getSinglePriceAsync(wep, skin, wear, stattrak) {
    return Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject) { // may be `Q.promise(...)` (lower case P) depending on Q version.
        csgomarket.getSinglePrice(wep, skin, wear, stattrak, function(err, result) {
            if(err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Now, you want `getPrice()` to return a promise that settles when all the individual `getSinglePriceAsync()` promises settle, which is trivial :

```
var getPrice = function(theData) {
    var promises = [];//array in which to accumulate promises 
    theData.skins.forEach(function(s) {
        theData.skinData[s] = {};
        wears.forEach(function(w) {
            promises.push(getSinglePriceAsync(theData.weapon, s, w, false).then(function(data) {
                theData.skinData[data.skin][data.wear] = data;
            }));
        });
    });
    //return a single promise that will settle when all the individual promises settle.
    return Q.allSettled(promises).then(function() {
        return theData;
    });
}
```

However, `theData.skinData[data.skin][data.wear]` will simplify slightly to  `theData.skinData[s][w]` :

```
var getPrice = function(theData) {
    var promises = [];//array in which to accumulate promises 
    theData.skins.forEach(function(s) {
        theData.skinData[s] = {}; // 
        wears.forEach(function(w) {
            promises.push(getSinglePriceAsync(theData.weapon, s, w, false).then(function(data) {
                theData.skinData[s][w] = data;
            }));
        });
    });
    //return a single promise that will settle when all the individual `promises` settle.
    return Q.allSettled(promises).then(function() {
        return theData;
    });
}
```

This simplification would work because the outer `forEach(function() {...})` causes `s` to be trapped in a closure.

As `getPrice()` now returns a promise, it must be used as follows :

```
getPrice(myData).then(function(data) {
    // use `data` here.
}).catch(function(e) {
    //something went wrong!
    console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for all the help! To make it work I had to make a few changes. Should I edit your answer to reflect the changes I made?

Comment: Yes please, go for it. I'll be interested to see what you had to change.

Comment: Nick, ok I approved your edit after a little tidying.

Answer (score 0):

Your way to do is very complex.

I think the best way is to do 1 request for all prices. Now, for each price you do a request.
If you have a list (array) with data that's need for the request, the return value should be a list with the prices.

If approach above is not possible, you can read more about batching http requests: http://jonsamwell.com/batching-http-requests-in-angular/

Answer (score 0):

Need some clarification - Are you trying to run this on the Client side? Looks like this is running inside a nodejs program on server side. If so, wouldn't you rather push this logic to the client side and handle with Ajax. I believe the browser is better equipped to handle multiple http request-responses.

Comment: This has to be on server side. The browser blocks my requests to Steam since it does not support JSONP as seen in my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634093/error-on-get-request-to-steam-market.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post much info about your csgoMarket.getSinglePrice function I wrote one that uses returns a promise. This will then allow you to use Q.all which you should read up on as it would really help in your situation.

I've created an inner and outer loop arrays to hold our promises. This code is completely untested since you didn't put up a fiddle.

```
var getPrice = function(theData) {
    var wep = theData.weapon;
    var completed = 0;
    var promises_outer = [] //array to hold the arrays of our promises

    for (var i = 0; i < theData.skins.length; i++) {
        var currSkin = theData.skins[i];
        theData.skinData[currSkin] = {};
        var promises_inner = [] // an array to hold our promises

        for (var k = 0; k < wears.length; k++) { //wears.length is referenced to below but not decalared anywhere in the function. It's either global or this function sits somewhere where it has access to it
            promises_inner.push(csgomarket.getSinglePrice(wep, currSkin, wears[k], false))
        }
        promises_outer.push(promises_inner)
    }

    promises_outer.forEach(function(el, index){
        var currSkin = theData.skins[index]
        theData.skinData[currSkin] = {}
        Q.all(el).then(function(data){  //data is an array of results in the order you made the calls
            if(data){
                theData.skinData[data.skin][data.wear] = data
            }
        })
    })
}

var csgomarket = {}
csgomarket.getSinglePrice = function(wep, currSkin, wears, someBoolean){
    return Q.promise(function (resolve, reject){
        //do your request or whatever you do
        var result = true
        var data = {
            skin : "cool one",
            wear : "obviously"
        }
        var error = new Error('some error that would be generated')
        if(result){
            resolve(data)
        } else {
            reject(error)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a try sometime today and get back to you. Sorry for not including  that. Here is the function though https://github.com/httpNick/csgo-market/blob/master/index.js